# How to tailor my resume after getting fired?

Tags: resume, termination, employment

A bit of history:

I'm in my mid-30s and finished university in 2015. English is my second language, and my verbal and written communication skills are not that great. 
I had been driving Uber for 2 years when I landed this job, only to lose it 8 months later.

At work (engineering trainee job), all my co-workers were assigned to a senior engineer to be mentored but my mentor was my manager. I was finding it hard to ask her for help without her judging me. Every one of my co-workers used to come to me for help because I was the most knowledgeable amongst us, but my manager never saw me helping them (ironically, I was helping a co-worker when she called me out to tell me that my employment was terminated).

Basically, she had a better picture about my co-workers than me, even though my co-workers knew that I was very good at my job, except the part that apparently got me fired - the documenting writing part.

Early on at the start of my job, I mentioned to her that I'm a computer geek and love programming without programming experience, so after a few weeks of training, she gave me the hardest program (Varian Assembly Program) and I was struggling to finish the task by the deadline. In the meantime, she gave me an even bigger and harder program to work on, while my documents were under review by the mentors. Before her, I had two other mentors and each was guiding me to a different path, which caused her to become my mentor.

These transfer of mentorship, delayed my project, and when she was my mentor, I was afraid of asking her for any help. And whenever I went to other seniors for help, she used to eyeball me. Long story short, after giving her my final document twice and she commenting and rejecting it each time, she gave me a written warning that I have to deliver a final document by certain date. When I did, she was till not happy and the next day she fired me.

She told me this in a private room along with another senior who asked me for help just two days ago. Hell, at the beginning even my manager was showing my work to others as a sample to be followed. She even used my template, diagrams, presentations etc. for others. Every one of my co-workers, used my final documents and changed its contents and got their documents reviewed, verified, and approved, except me.

I did all the heavy lifting and came up with a test bed that no one had, that would have, otherwise, delayed their projects by several weeks, but she didn't see that.

I am not a slacker. I am an honest, hardworking, and smart person, but it seems to be insufficient to succeed in this God-forsaken world.

Anyway, when it comes to understanding something, my only problem is that I have to learn something before writing about it, while my co-workers didn't care about learning/understanding and so they used to go to others, get the pieces and write something that made my manager happy and get the job done. While I see and know my co-workers' skills, I cannot be like them, even though I want to be.

Now, it's almost two months since I was let go and I don't know how to fill this gap and how to avoid the last employment. I'm tempted into putting the word "present" as the date, but I know that companies will check. What should I do? The only thing that I think of is that since this job was a contract and I had to register a corporation, I am thinking of putting my job as the employee of my own company (XYZ Inc.). Other than that, I’m totally lost.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks. (Writing at 2am).

[EDIT]
My situation is different because I have a registered corporation and was basically providing service to this company. I could use my experience under my own company or under my employer's company. However, if I use my experience under my company, I don't have a website and the company address is the same as my home address and don't know how it will come out in the verification of employment check.

Comment: if the job was a trainee position its not weird that you were only in it 8 months. Just use some ambiguous language when describing to people what happened and use the word Trainee in the position title on your CV.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what country you're in.

If you're in the US, you usually won't have to disclose that you were fired, and your former company is unlikely to disclose it as well.  Due to concerns about legal trouble of some sort, most US companies won't give negative *or* positive feedback about a former employee.  All they'll do is confirm that you worked there from date X to date Y.

As far as the empty two months, simply say that your contract ended and you've been looking for the right opportunity.  If someone actually presses the matter ("You didn't have something lined up before the contract ended?"), simply say ruefully (but not too negatively) that unfortunately some employers don't feel that contractors need much notice when a contract is complete, or something along those lines.

It's likely that most companies won't care about any of the above; they'll just care whether you're capable of doing the work they want you to do.

Answer (score 1):

> The only thing that I think of is that since this job was a contract and I had to register a corporation, I am thinking of putting my job as the employee of my own company (XYZ Inc.).

You answered your own question. Since this was a contract, simply put this on your resume as such:

[your made-up title, e.g. Principal, Owner, etc.], My Computer Consulting Inc. (January 2017-Present)

- Contract with XYZ Corp (January 2017 - August 2017).
- Programmed components of XYZ Software in ABC language.
- [additional description on types of tasks you completed].

When you interview for future jobs, you can simply say your contract ended after 8 months. You would be telling the truth because as a contractor, getting fired essentially means end of contract. When you interview, you do not need to elaborate on how/why the contract ended, as that can happen for a variety of business reasons. Good luck!

Comment: This depends, if he was contracting through an agency, they are the agency's employee, not their own.